# Sign a file with SMIME in C#

Tags: c#

I need sign a file with sime in C#, similar to OpenSSL next command line:

```
openssl smime -outform der -nodetach -signer my509.crt -inkey myprivatekey.rsa -in myfile.txt -out myfile.out
```

In c# I useBouncy Castle library for read key file in PEM format.

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;

private void sign_TRA_alt()
{
  // Read x509
  X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("my598.crt");
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

  // Read private key
  using (TextReader privateKeyTextReader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("myprivate.rsa")))
  {
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair readKeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(privateKeyTextReader).ReadObject();
    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKeyParams = ((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)readKeyPair.Private);
    RSAParameters rsa_params = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKeyParams); 
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsa_params);
  }

  // Join private key to x509
  certificate.PrivateKey = rsa;
  
  // Sign file 
  String tra;

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("myfile.txt"))
  {
    tra = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }

  ContentInfo contInfo = new ContentInfo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tra));
  SignedCms signed = new SignedCms(contInfo, true);
  CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);

  try
  {
    signed.ComputeSignature(signer);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log_message("Error: " + e.Message );
  }

  String dataSigned = Convert.ToBase64String(signed.Encode());
}
```

When execute this code an exception is fired when ComputeSignature is executed. The exception message say "The public key is invalid" ....